# Two view on single page in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am creating an application in AngularJs for Mobile and Tablet device. 
I have used ng-view to render different html partial pages based on url with help of $routeProvider's templateUrl.

It is working fine in case of mobile.
But In Case of tablet requirement is different , I have to show two partial html pages( of mobile) in one page of tablet(since screen width is large as compare to mobile) but I have to no idea how to do this.

Can any one provide some hit to accomplished this task.

Thank you.

Comment: Well, I can't see any approaches you may have thought so it's unlikely you are going to get much help here. Please, try to improve your question by adding more information, options you have thought and preferably some code.

Comment: Could you give an example of the two different views? Is this something you could achieve more simply with responsive CSS?

Answer (score 0):

ngRoute only allows one view. You could try ui.router which allows nested views, multiple views etc.
Or use ng-include for 2nd view to include different templates dynamicly. You could create a directive which does this or simply use a variable on $rootScope for 2nd template.

```
<div ng-include="secondTemplateName"></div>
```

And when you have to change the 2nd view:

```
$rootScope.secondTemplateName = "...";
```

Using ui.router might be the cleanest solution.

Comment: You don't need to (and shouldn't) use `$rootScope` for this. You can pass data along with a route, even with `ng-route` just by setting a property (as you do with `template` and `controller`), then access it with `$route.current.whateverProperty`

Comment: Good idea .. how ever, a directive or a root scope is easier when dynamicly changing the partials to load, it is best to use route if related partials are static for each route. Also if using route, must inject $route in to controller and assign to $scope. Or assign it to $rootScope :).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/AV3dSH3360teHdEl2Icc) is what you want.

Its a working example.